# HTML/Refresh.BC trojan на пустом месте Eset Smart Security 9?

Tags: безопасность

Делаю проект на локальном сервере. Сборка, **OpenServer**.
Когда захожу первый раз на свой же сайт, выдает что там троян.

```
    Threat found
This web page contains potentially dangerous content.

Threat: HTML/Refresh.BC trojan

Access to it has been blocked. Your computer is safe.

Open ESET Knowledgebase  |  www.eset.com
```

**Проверив антивирусниками** (Eset, Dr.Web, AVZ - все чисто). Просмотрел все файлы вручную (ларавел 5.3, вьюшка, контроллер, и подгружаемые скрипты особо ничего нет) все так же чисто, только мой код, стороннего нет. 
Раньше такого не было.

**В чем может быть проблемма?**

Comment: Если вы на все 100% уверены, что никакого вредоносного ПО там нет... В антивирусе? У них бывают ложные срабатывания. Возможно, в очередном обновлении базы пришла очень слабая сигнатура.

Comment: уверен на 100% что все чисто.